# python bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, bit-shift

i am trying to combine several variables into 1 element of a bytearray.

I have the variables:
version, padding, extension, cc
of sizes: 2b, 1b, 1b, 4b

how do i combine them in that order as one byte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variables are integers, you can just use bit-shifts and bitwise-or operations to form a value comprised of 8-bits and then store that where you want in the bytearray.

```
ba[i] = version << 6 | padding << 5 | extension << 4 | cc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pack them into a byte using shift and bit-masking.

```
version, padding, extension, cc = 2, 0, 1, 3
byte = ((version & 3) << 6) | ((padding & 1) << 5) | ((extension & 1) << 4) | (cc & 7)
byte
# OUT: 147
```

Note that you have to mask them first or else if the value exceeds the range it will clobber the other fields.